# I'm confused and I need help

Tags: riddle

I don't understand any of this. I'm trying to win a contest. I can be found in clothing, canned goods, stores, libraries, storage bins, and schools. What am I?

Comment: Are the first 2 lines part of the riddle?

Comment: My guess: "_Matter_"

Comment: You are....a poorly written riddle.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing

> Label

Clothings have

> Brand label

Canned goods have

> That piece of paper wrapped around it.

Stores has

> Price labels

Library uses

> Labels on each book for the call number

Storage bin has

> Labels to mark what's inside

Schools

> School kids have labels on their belongings.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

> Atoms. They are found in everything you mentioned.

Comment: To the people downvoting, tell me why. I'm not sure what part of my answer doesn't fit the riddle.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to include a detailed explanation, given the information in the question?

Comment: I mean if you look at the answer, I'm not sure what explanation is needed unless the person doesn't know what the thing is that I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Hmm... now that I look more closely at it, I do see the issue. My apologies!

Comment: All good, probably just people angry that I have such a general answer, but it fits the guidelines so w/e.

Comment: Since atoms can be found in anything, this answer could, on the face of it, answer any riddle concerned with objects. Thus it's not a very useful answer to any riddle.